# How can hacker take advantage of array or pointers

Tags: c, security

I am graduate looking to find work soon but I have a question about code security.

In Java there are no out-of-bound arrays and there are no pointers which suggests Java is more secure than C. In C these out-of-bounds arrays can cause stack corruption or buffer overflow and dangling pointers. In an interview I may be asked "how can a hacker take advantages of these?"

How do I go about answering this?

Examples are welcome.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1354/

Comment: I think you're misguided here. Many of these issues can arise as a result of poor design alone, never mind hackers; Java just provides an insulating layer. Allow me to illustrate: you have enough money to pay for 1 item, and you ask for 10, which are provided as requested. You're expected to pay for the other 9, right? C makes you code this yourself, whereas the JVM simply kills your application due to an uncaught exception. Aside: the fact that Heartbleed is a bug in a widely deployed cryptographic library is the only reason it was such a big deal, but it was due to poor design, not just C.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could talk specifically about Heartbleed (there is a ton of documentation out there).

Basically, there was an api call that could be made via the network, where your code would request a communication keep-alive, which would normally look like:

```
You: send me "potato", which is 6 chars.
Response: potato
```

However, there was no check that the text requested, and the length of the text sent in were aligned, so you could do this:

```
You: send me "potato", which is 512 chars.
Response potato&&&&#8388325099#((#(#)%#(((#%)password:1234#(%()#%((#%#(#%)(#)(%)(##()JFJFEOIJF#)J(JF)(#J)(#J#)(J#))J#....
```

Where the responding computer would send potato, plus 506 bytes of what is essentially the stack around that local variable, which could contain almost anything, including passwords, etc.

That a good enough example?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your job involves security, I don't think that you'll be asked this. Identifying vulnerabilities is relatively easy but exploiting them is hard, and I think that most employers would be perfectly happy knowing that you know you need to check your bounds.

billjamesdev [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36708316/251153) information disclosure through overflow, and this is basically what the Heartbleed bug was about. However, there are much worse possible outcomes, the most famous of which being arbitrary, remote code execution: basically, somebody else running any code that they like in your program because of a software vulnerability. Stack-based buffer overflows are easier to exploit to get RCE, but heap-based buffers can also be exploited to some extent.

In this tiny function:

```
int foo() {
    char bar[4];
}
```

The array `bar` lives on the stack. One other interesting thing that lives on the stack, though, is the function's return address. If you overwrite that address, when the function returns, it will jump to a location of your choosing instead of where the developer thought that it would go back. Say that you have these two functions:

```
int main() {
    char bar[4];
    scanf("Enter no more than 4 characters: %s\n", bar);
}

int bar() {
    system("sh"); // starts a shell on Linux
}
```

and assume that `bar` lives at the memory address 0x41414141 (which is highly unlikely, but it makes the demonstration easier because 0x41 is the ASCII code for 'A'). If you run that program on Linux and input this:

```
Enter no more than 4 characters: 00001111AAAA
```

On x86, this will fill up the character buffer with ASCII zeroes, overwrite a special value called the parent's base frame pointer (it is very important to your program but hackers don't usually need to care about it) with ASCII ones, and overwrite the return address with `0x41414141`. When `main` returns, instead of terminating the program, it will start a shell.

There are a lot of variations on attacks, but the basic idea is that buffer overflows may allow a hacker to hijack the execution flow of your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of one I seen recently. This is a bit contrived but it's quite easy to understand.

We have a dispatch table with some functions in it and due to an error we're able to call the wrong function.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SETBIT(X,Y)     X|=(1ULL<<(Y))

typedef void (*method)(void);

void unsafe();
void safe();

void safe(void) {
  printf("anyone can call this\n");
}
void unsafe(void) {
  fprintf(stderr, "wtf, how did this get called\n");
  abort();
}
static method dispatch_table[2] = {0};

typedef struct node {
  union container {
    float fdata;
    int idata;
  } data;
  uint32_t func;
} Node;

int main(void) {
  size_t nsize1 = sizeof(Node);
  assert(nsize1 == 8); 
  assert(sizeof(int)    == 4); 
  assert(sizeof(float)  == 4); 
  assert(sizeof(double) == 8); 

  dispatch_table[0] = &safe;
  dispatch_table[1] = &unsafe;
  Node  n   = {.data.fdata = 10.0};
  n.func = 0;

  //The problem starts here
  void *bad  = (void*)&n;
  uint64_t *badder = (uint64_t*)bad;
  SETBIT(*badder, 32);// Off by one error
  printf("%d\n", n.func);
  dispatch_table[n.func]();
  return 0;
}
```